# Cannot find component with identifier in View JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I was trying to show messages using a p:growl like this.to be updated on the OnRowSelect Method of a Data Table lazy loading like this

```
<p:growl id="applyMessages" showDetail="false" global="true" /> and     <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{editBean.onRowSelect}" update=":studyPlanEditForm:display applyMessages"/>
```

but got the error like this 
Cannot find component with identifier "applyMessages" in view.
Please Help.

Comment: check for applyMessages in the view source of the page rendered. There might be some prefix required to be added to applyMessages like :YourForm_ID:applyMessages

Comment: does it works seperetly , like this ?  update=":studyPlanEditForm:display" and update="applyMessages" works for you , is it producing any errors ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the source code of your page in browser. Then identify the `p:growl` markup and its generated client-id. It surely is longer than `applyMessages` and has a prefix similar to `containerID:applyMessages`. Use this id in your `update` attribute of the ajax call.

Comment: Hi, interestingly in the view source the same id applyMessages is listed.When I change the update=":studyPlanEditForm:display applyMessages" order ie applyMessages first and then display second , the error message is getting for component display.Please Help.

Comment: But is it inside the same form as `display`? If it has no prefix `studyPlanEditForm` it indicates that it is _not_ inside this form. Btw Do you use `h:form` tags instead of simple html `<form>`?

Comment: Hi Matt Handy, the form id is studyPlanEditForm,Yes I am using h:form.

Comment: From my experience it is a good practice to use `p:growl` as a very first component since it doesn't have to be inside a `h:form`. So put it outside a `h:form` and then update it with its id. `update=":applyMessages"`

Comment: Hi if there is only one id(componenet) it goes fine, the problem is when I try to update the second one.

Comment: @user1281029 just a guess , do you have nested forms on page (form inside form? ) anyway post more code...

Comment: @Fallup , nope , primefaces accepts both "," and " " ...(Matt's just told me that :) )

Comment: Hi,I solved the problem by giving only the formid so that all components will get updated though not partial.